# SyncFramework with SQL Server

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I have three tables in SQL Server 2008

- Account
- Case
- CaseStatus

Table `Case` has a reference using column `AccountId` to `AccountTable`, and `CaseStatus` has a reference on `caseId` to table `Case`.

I need to sync these three table depending on `AccountId(AccountTable)`. Please help me to write code (template) in Microsoft Sync Framework

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use an AccountId selected on the client side to sync data from all three tables to the client, but limited to the AccountId.

Pass along the accountId as a parameter when filtering (see [How to: Filter Data for Database Synchronization (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928701%28SQL.110%29.aspx))

Next, you need to rewrite the filterclause with subselects to something like this, assuming you name your parameter 'AccountId':
Account table: `side.AccountId = @AccountId`
Case table: `side.AccountId = @AccountId`
CaseStatus table: `side.CaseId in (Select CaseId from Case Where AccountId = @AccountId)`

Answer (score 0):

are you filtering on AccountID?

you can set the FilterClause for the Case table to "side.AccountId in (Select AccountId from AccountTable)"

and for CaseStatus table to "side.CaseId in (Select CaseId from Case)"

Comment: Hear I give only Account Id then depending on Account Id  I have to retrieve data from all the three tables . Please help me

Comment: @Shankar: You already left a comment, why do you need to edit and paste your comment there?

Comment: @Shankar - StephaneT's post should do the trick. you have to change the FilterClause for CaseStatus to query from the_tracking table though as the inner query will not pick up Delete's 

e.g : 
CaseStatus table: side.CaseId in (Select CaseId from Case_tracking Where AccountId = @AccountId)